# Email sqlite database table contents in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, email

I have a sqlite database called PERSONS.db and a table called RECORD_TABLE can i find some references or code snippets for emailing the table contents in a table format in android

Comment: just fetch data and build your custom content string to attach in email!

Comment: *"some references or code snippets"* are you too lazy to write your own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these tutorials,

[Android Sqlite Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

[Java Mail Sending](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)

You have to create the table format yourself.

Comment: one more good sqlite android tutorial to start http://www.quicktips.in/basic-android-sqlite-database-exampletutorial/